# Output query result to file?

Tags: mysql

The below query works

```
SELECT *
  FROM some_table 
 LIMIT 1 
  INTO outfile 'some_file.txt';
```

but how would you write the result of this statement to file

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS INTO OUTFILE 'some_file.txt'
```

or any other show statements, getting error using `into outfile`?

Error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE "some_file.txt"' at line 1

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO OUTFILE "some_file.txt"' at line 1

Comment: also paste the other query

Comment: @splucena: Are you using MySQL client console or any other?

Comment: @zzlalani SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS INTO OUTFILE 'some_file.txt'. Ravinder shell, root privilege.

Comment: chck my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You CANNOT. INTO OUTFILE can be used only with SELECT STATEMENT... hence you're getting 1064 (syntax-error). Please refer to the documentation here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html

It always says-**"SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE..."**

You need to use console in order to get output of SHOW commands or anything apart of 'SELECT' statement. Here's how you do it:

Follow the syntax below:

```
mysql --user root --password=sunny -e"show databases">"D:\\test\\OutFile.txt";
```

Above statement will give your all the databases in outfile.

```
mysql --user root --password=sunny --database=mydb -e"describe myTable">"D:\\test\\OutFile.txt";
```

This will  output the description of your table.

HTH !

Comment: But how would you write show statements to file. Copying the result from the shell may not be convenient.